# Log command-line options passed to behave

Tags: logging, command-line-arguments, python-behave

I am launching python-behave with command-line options like (tests outputs is being written to a logfile)

```
behave -f json -D browser=safari -D browser_version=8 -D platform=MAC features
```

I want to log which command-line options are being passed to behave in a logfile, but I cannot find how to do in a documentation. I tried using `@capture` with `before_all` hook in my environment.py (nothing new logged)

UPDATE: I need to log only -D options and include them inside relevant json output.

Does anyone know how to setup custom logging in behave? Thanks!

Comment: You want to record *all* command line options, or just those passed with `-D`?

Comment: @Louis, just -D options

Answer (score 0):

Every options you set using the `--define` option are [stored](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html#cmdoption-D) in the `config` of your `context` object, under `userdata`. To retrieve them all, you could use something like this:

```
for option, value in context.config.userdata.iteritems():

    # do something here
```

You weren't really specific as to how you want to output them here, but you may want to just print them out.